# What will mathematicians do when they run out of letters in the Greek and English alphabets?

Tags: soft-question, notation, math-history

Like $x$, $y$, $z$ are commonly understood to be dimensions and $\theta$ is an angle, $\pi$ is a specific irrational constant, and $\tau$ is two times $\pi$, et cetera.

They must be running out of letters by now.
Is that a problem?
What's the solution?

Comment: Hebrew, Cyrillic, reusing letters as needed, .....

Comment: They already started to use the hebrew alphabet, like $\aleph_0$

Comment: Subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: Letters like $\pi$ are used for other things also, with the meaning clear from context.

Comment: Variations of the fonts are also used, such as bold for vectors.

Comment: it's not a problem, letters can be reused, and new fonts can be made. For example, $a,A,\mathcal A , \mathbb A$

Comment: computer scientists already solved this, just concatenate letters to make words, then the possibilities are endless

Comment: $\tau = 2\pi$, not half of it.

Comment: what about subscripts? You can always use $\alpha_1$,$\beta_3$, etc

Comment: ^ and that is why some differential geometry formulas start looking like centipedes crawling across the page

Answer (score 11):

This happened a long time ago. Which is why modern mathematics reads the way it does: We *declare* what our symbols will represent before proceeding with the rest of whatever it is we're doing.

Answer (score 11):

P. Halmos addressed the problem in his highly recommended paper [How to write mathematics](http://www.math.washington.edu/%7Elind/Resources/Halmos.pdf). Let me quote his advice (from the end of Section 6).

> As history progresses, more and more symbols get frozen. The standard
> examples are e, i and π, and, of course, 0,1,2,3,... (Who would dare
> write “Let 6 be a group.”?) A few other letters are almost frozen:
> many readers would fell offended if “n” were used for a complex
> number, “ε” for a positive integer, and “z” for a topological space.
> (A mathematician’s nightmare is a sequence nε that tends to 0 as ε
> becomes infinite.)
>
> Moral: do not increase the rigid frigidity. Think
> about the alphabet. It’s a nuisance, but it’s worth it. To save time
> and trouble later, think about the alphabet for an hour now; then
> start writing.

Comment: Some things get unfrozen though.  I've often seen people use $1_A$ to mean the identity morphism on A.

Comment: @QthePlatypus I thought something similar, in particular because J. H. Conway *does* use the notation $6$ for a group! But one difference may be that $6$ is always the name of a particular group (in this case, the cyclic one with $6$ elements), so you still won't see "Let $6$ be *a* group". In your example, you would never write "Let $1_A$ be *a* morphism," because it always means *that one particular morphism*!